# How to add two numbers in Java Programming

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x, y, sum;

        Scanner input = new input(system.in);

        input = parseInt32();


    }

}
```

here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    input cannot be resolved to a type
    input cannot be resolved to a type
    system cannot be resolved to a variable
    The method parseInt32() is undefined for the type Test

    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Comment: Where did you define the method named parseInt32() ?

Comment: You're trying to run code that can't compile. Never do that. Fix the compilation error that your compiler is complaining about before trying to run it.

Comment: I would like to allow the user to input to value before adding it up, do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: Check this with steps : [Java program to add two numbers](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2013/01/write-java-program-to-add-two-numbers_30.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `nextInt();` so something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("First number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("Second number: ");
    int y = input.nextInt();  

    int sum = x+y;

    System.out.println("Result: "+sum); 
}
```

Comment: As notes by @Mercifies, that should be System.in rather than system.in.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I got it correct!

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner input = new input(system.in);` 
should be 
`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`.

It's giving you an error because you are trying to set your input to an int conversion. It should look like this instead:

`x = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Umm... Yes and no. The error is because the method `parseInt32` is not defined.

Comment: I believe they are trying to use parseInt32 as a converter and even if it was defined as a method, you can't set a scanner object to a method. Maybe if she had create a type and set it to that, it could work.

Comment: Thanks guys for the solution, this time i got it correct!